# What is "matting"?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "matting" mean in this sentence? From Hemingway's Farewell to Arms

> Then beyond where the road was not protected by the hills it was screened by **matting** on the sides and over the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the following from the start of Chapter 9 of the same book, it may be clearer.

> The road was crowded and there were screens of corn
> stalk and straw matting on both sides and matting over
> the top so that it was like the entrance at a circus or a
> native village. We drove slowly in this matting-covered
> tunnel and came out on to a bare cleared space where
> the railway station had been.

It refers to mats woven out of straw. Straw is the stem of grain (wheat, barely, rye, corn, etc.) that is often discarded after the grain is harvested and separated from the plant. The picture shows an example of straw woven into matting intended to lay down on ground that has no plants growing on it and so reduce erosion.

[image]

Straw is a relatively cheap material, though not particularly durable nor strong. Matting can be used to provide shade, privacy, a wind break, etc.

Comment: The word is "mats" not "matts". "Mat" and "matt" are homophones which (once you understand what they mean) are difficult to confuse.

Comment: Do you mean that farmers actually went to the trouble to weave straw mats and roll them out in the fields back then?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev As stated, they were used for special purposes, some of which are listed.